# Wordpress Plugin Dev : Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new on plugin development.

I'm try to create a custom Printable form page in wp-admin to create Customer Postal Address.

very Similar [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-order-address-print/)

when administrator click on **"print Address"** link , pop-up `template.php` page with customer address and information for print address

[image]

**The Problem is :**

I get fatal Error when click on **print order** anchor tag and i can't run any `wordpress` action on `template.php`:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\address generator\template.php on line 4**

```
 <?php
    /**
    * Plugin Name: Address Generator
    * Plugin URI: http://CGTV.ir
    * Description:Generate Postal Label for Parcel
    * Version: 1.0 or 
    * Author: Hamed Mayahian
    * Author URI: CGTV.ir
    * License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL12
    */
    // ADDING COLUMN TITLES (Here 2 columns)
    /*define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
    include( MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'template.php');
    */      

      require_once(ADDRESS__PLUGIN_DIR .'template.php');




    add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column',11);
    function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
    {
       //add columns
        $columns['my-column1'] = __( 'چاپ آدرس','theme_slug');
       return $columns;

    }

    // adding the data for each orders by column (example)
    add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'cbsp_credit_details', 10, 2 );
    function cbsp_credit_details( $column )
    {
        global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;
        $order_id = $the_order->id;

        switch ( $column )
        {
            case 'my-column1' :
                $myVarOne = wc_get_order_item_meta( $order_id, '_the_meta_key1', true );
                echo $myVarOne;
                echo "<a target='_blank' href='".plugins_url( 'template.php' , __FILE__ )."?order=$order_id'>Print Address</a>";
                break;


        }
    }
```

**Template.php**

```
<?php


add_action('init', 'my_init', 1);
function my_init(){

    global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;

    $id = $_GET['order'];
    $order = new WC_Order($id);
    $address    = $order->get_billing_address();

    $customer_id = get_current_user_id();
if($_GET['order'] == "") {
  // no username entered
  echo "آدرس پیدا نشد";
} else {
  echo "Hello, " . $address;
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain what the template.php file is doing? It's unclear what you area trying to achieve. Why can't you have it in the same file as the plugin file? I would also advise you to load your entire plugin on the `woocommerce_loaded` hook, that way you will be sure that all WooCommerce functions are ready.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947979/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-add-action?rq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094471/wordpress-plugin-how-to-resolve-call-to-undefined-function-add-action-as-wel?rq=1)

Comment: @helgatheviking both not work

Comment: It *is* the same because you are trying to call WordPress functions on a file `template.php` that is outside of WordPress and hence WordPress is not loaded. So the solution is to *stop* loading `template.php` and trying to have it run WordPress functions.

Comment: Please add more _relevant_ information before posting a bounty. The one response has _plenty of detail_, but is not very specific because we're not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gant thanks for your comment , but i think that's very clear what i looking for. by the way i add more detail. please ask a question if you don't understand my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

template.php file is out of Wordpress then we are not access Wordpress core functions. Include this file in main plugin is works properly but when we access by url directly this file then we can't access Wordpress core functions because we are not follow Wordpress stranded. Order list table have button called url generate like something is http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/address%20generator/template.php?order=5147. When we  access this get following error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in.."

First comment this line in your main plugin file.

```
 // require_once('template.php');
```

Changes in template.php file.

```
<?php

require('../../../wp-load.php');


    $id = $_GET['order'];
    $order = new WC_Order($id);
    $address    = $order->get_billing_address();

    $customer_id = get_current_user_id();
if($_GET['order'] == "") {
  // no username entered
  echo "آدرس پیدا نشد";
} else {
  echo "Hello, " . $address;
}
```

But this is not a Wordpress stranded solution. User @helgatheviking is provide best solution for this.

Comment: the @helgatheviking solution not work for my unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, I can only suggest the following as an improvement in how you are launching your plugin and how you are displaying the custom column.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Shop Column Link
 * Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39280792/383847
 * Description: Link for shop column to display billing address
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: helgatheviking
 * Author URI: http://kathyisawesome.com/
 * Text Domain: your-plugin
 * Domain Path: /languages
 *
 * Copyright: © 2015 Kathy Darling and Manos Psychogyiopoulos
 * License: GNU General Public License v3.0
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */


// add all your hooks only when woocommerce has fully loaded it's files
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'custom_address_generator_init' );
function custom_address_generator_init(){
    add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column',11);
    add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'cbsp_credit_details',11);
}

// add your custom column
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
   //add columns
    $columns['my-column1'] = __( 'چاپ آدرس', 'your-plugin');
   return $columns;

}

// adding the data for each orders by column (example)
function cbsp_credit_details( $column )
{
    global $the_order;
    $order_id = $the_order->id;

    switch ( $column )
    {
        case 'my-column1' :
            $myVarOne = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_the_meta_key1', true );
            echo $myVarOne;
            $url = add_query_arg( array( 'order_id' => $order_id, 'my-action' => 'do-something-cool', ), wp_nonce_url( admin_url(), 'my_order_nonce', 'my_nonce' ) );
            printf( '<a class="custom-class" href="%s" data-order_id="%s">%s</a>', $url, $order_id, __( 'Print Address', 'your-plugin' ) );
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2** We're going to create a link to the front-end so we can load a custom template via `template_include`. It should have enough security on it to keep it limited to only the appropriate users.

```
// load a custom template when special link is clicked
add_action( 'template_include', 'my_template', 1 );
function my_template(){

    if( isset( $_GET['my-action'] ) && $_GET['my-action'] == 'do-something-cool' && isset( $_GET['order_id'] ) && current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $_GET['order_id'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['my_nonce'], 'my_order_nonce' ) ){

        return untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '/templates/my-template.php';

    }
}
```

Then a `/templates/my-plugin.php` file in your plugin folder:

```
<?php

$order_id = intval( $_GET['order_id'] );
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

if( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ){
    $address    = $order->get_formatted_billing_address ();
    if( $address ){
        printf( '%s, %s', __( 'Hello', 'your-plugin' ), $address );
    } else {
        _e( 'No billing address', 'your-plugin' );
    }
} else {
    _e( 'Not a valid order ID', 'your-plugin' );
}
```

I've dropped the `my_init()` function in favor of `my_template()` which will now load a custom template (`/templates/my-template.php`) via the `template_include` filter. This template is loaded by WordPress and has all the WordPress functions available for you to use.

Comment: the problem is not adding column, that work fine,the problem is second section of my code , when the `<a target='_blank' href='".plugins_url( 'template.php' , __FILE__ )."?order=$order_id'>Print Address</a>` is clicked

Comment: actually i want to know why the function on second page `"template.php" ` not working

Comment: When you hit the `template.php` page, WP is not loaded. That's why you get a fatal error and why your approach is faulty. I'll edit with a suggestion, but since I can't tell what you are trying to do it's just a suggestion and not a cut-paste solution.

Comment: thanks for you help , let me explain, the `template.php` in my plugin folder,so i want to create some address label plugin like this:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-order-address-print/

Comment: So i want to send order_id on that page,load order information then create label print.but i can't load any function to `template.php`.and i don't know why

Comment: please let me know how to load WP on that page and get function to work.otherwise how possible to use second page on my plugin to create template for address label.

Comment: You will be better served by telling WordPress when to load that page. See my latest edit. Also, next time, please add the information about what you are trying to actually *do* (and why) to the question. More detail is almost always better. It really helps people help you faster.

Comment: I tested it and it does work, so I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. Take the original plugin and add the `my_template()` function from Edit 2. Then make sure your `/templates/my-template.php` is in the right place (in your new plugin folder). Try turning on `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to see if you have any errors.